# Basic Math, exponents and algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the equation
$$\frac{x_1^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{{x_2^{-\frac{1}{2}}}} = p_l/p_2$$

How do I get $x_2$ on its own?

I have
$$x_2^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{p_2(x_1^{-\frac{1}{2}})}{p_1}$$
And if you have a useful link that reviews this info, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Square both sides:
$$
\frac{x_1^{-1}}{x_2^{-1}}=\frac{p_1^2}{p_2^2}
$$
Rewrite the left hand side:
$$
\frac{x_1^{-1}}{x_2^{-1}}=
\frac{1/x_1}{1/x_2}=\frac{1}{x_1}\left(\frac{1}{x_2}\right)^{-1}=
\frac{1}{x_1}x_2=\frac{x_2}{x_1}
$$
Thus your equality is
$$
\frac{x_2}{x_1}=\frac{p_1^2}{p_2^2}
$$
or
$$
x_2=\frac{p_1^2}{p_2^2}x_1
$$

Answer (score 2):

By definition, if $x \neq 0$, then

$$x^{-n} = \frac{1}{x^n}$$

Thus,

$$x_1^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{x_1^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$

If we make the substitution $n = -m$ in the equation

$$x^{-n} = \frac{1}{x^n}$$

we obtain

$$x^{m} = \frac{1}{x^{-m}}$$

Hence,

$$\frac{1}{x_2^{-\frac{1}{2}}} = x_2^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Therefore, we can rewrite the equation

$$\frac{x_1^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{x_2^{-\frac{1}{2}}} = \frac{p_1}{p_2}$$

in the form

$$\frac{x_2^{\frac{1}{2}}}{x_1^{\frac{1}{2}}} = \frac{p_1}{p_2}$$

which we can solve for $x_2$ by multiplying both sides by $x_1^{\frac{1}{2}}$ to obtain

$$x_2^{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{p_1x_1^{\frac{1}{2}}}{p_2}$$

then squaring both sides to obtain

$$x_2 = \frac{p_1^2x_1}{p_2^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there: from $x_2^{-1/2} = \frac{p_2x_1^{-1/2}}{p_1}$, take the reciprocal of both sides and then square both sides:
\begin{align*}
  x_2^{-1/2} &= \frac{p_2x_1^{-1/2}}{p_1} \\
  x_2^{1/2} &= \frac{p_1}{p_2x_1^{-1/2}} \\
  x_2 &= \frac{p_1^2}{p_2^2x_1^{-1}} = \frac{x_1p_1^2}{p_2^2}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If you have
$$u^{-\frac{1}{2}}=v$$
square both sides to get
$$u^{-1}=v^2$$
Now just re-arrange the variables:
$$u^{-1}v^{-2}=1$$
$$v^{-2}=u$$
Can you go from here?